# Storing text in db: how to choose varchar size (considering formatting), storing formatting separately?

Tags: php, database, validation, database-design, input

How to best choose a size for a varchar/text/... column in a (mysql) database (let's assume the text the user can type into a text area should be max 500 chars), considering that the user also might use formatting (html/bb code/...), which is not visible to the user and should not affect the max 500 chars text size...??

1) theoretically, to prevent any error, the varchar size has to be almost endless, if the user e.g. uses 20 links like this (http://[huge number of chars]) or whatever... - or not?

2) should/could you save formatting in a separate column, to e.g. not give an index (like FULLTEXT) wrong values (words that are contained in formatting but not in the real text)?

If yes, how to best do this? do you remember at which point the formatting was used, save this point and the formatting and when outputting put this information together?

(php/mysql, java script, jquery)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It may be wrong, but in my experience, when storing any content that you know "could" be longer than a limit your thinking to impose, set it as `text`.

Comment: @Gavin: thx, just I read about `text` being slower as `varchar`, as for text mysql has to perform row read (see [forums.mysql.com](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105984#msg-105984))

Comment: If that is the case, then you must rely on third party solutions to prevent the user from using more than xx characters. For full text search purposes, the only solution I can think of is, store the normal content within one column and store the text without any formatting in another.

Comment: @Chris Slower for _what_? What is "slower" and what is "faster" often changes depending on your usage pattern. I'm not an expert on how MySQL stores BLOBs, but must DBMSes will partially or completely store them outside rows, which will actually make rows narrower, speeding-up operations that _don't_ touch BLOBs.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: of course, you are right. well, but it is not only about binary but also textual data, is it not? I not only mean storing new lines etc but e.g. html-tags (when using a wysiwyg-editor)...

Comment: @Chris Again, I'm no expert on MySQL in this regard, but in most DBMSes CLOBs (which is what MySQL `TEXT` is) are stored in essentially the same way as BLOBs. The difference is only in how they are compared and sorted  (i.e. CLOBs have a character set and collation sequence). A clue that the same is true in MySQL is that `TEXT` and `BLOB` are [documented together](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html).

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to consider in the amount of formatting characters.

If you do not, to avoid data loss, you need to use much more space for the text on the database and check the length of prior record before save or use full text.

Keep the same data twice in one table is not a good solution, it all depends on your project, but usually better it's filter formating on php.

Comment: yeah, thank you ShaaD. Limiting the amount of formatting characters is a good idea. Do you have any ideas how to best put this into practice? I only need very basic features (like `a href`, `bold`, `italic`), so I don't know wether to use a 3rd party WYSIWYG editor, as it only adds a lot of complexity and unforeseeable problems, probably needs to be updated regularly etc. How would you suggest to solve this?

Comment: You can use BBcodes, php has a good class to work with them. on the client side is enough to make the buttons wrapping the selected text into tags.